# Official Ubuntu Utopic 14.10 repositories offline?

Tags: apt, updates, 14.10, official-repositories

My desktop has been inactive for around 2 months until today, when I get to run the `sudo apt-get update` it is printing this 404 errors, most of them from the official Ubuntu repos, what is happening?

Complete error part of the apt's trace:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 reached end-of-live on 2015-07-31

Comment: oh thatś sad, I guess this will ends up in fresh installing in the next few days

Comment: @GermanRosales You don't need to reinstall if you don't want to. It's possible to upgrade directly to 15.04 and then 15.10.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have tried this dist upgrades before and they resulted in no good

Comment: I did it several times and never had a problem...